# the usestate hook is not working in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

Hello Guys This is how my code looks like

```
export default function Billing() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [balance, setBalance] = useState('0.00');
    const [upcoming, setUpcoming] = useState('0.00');
    const [lastmonth, setLastmonth] = useState('0.00');
    const [header, setHeader] = useState('Please Enter The Amount');
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [amountstate, setAmountstate] = useState(false);
    
    const [amounthelper, setAmounthelper] = useState('');
    const [sairam, setSairam] = useState(0);
    const onchange = async (e) => {
        console.log(sairam) 
        setSairam({amount: e.target.value})
    }
    const [modalchild, setModalchild] = useState(<>
    <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
       <TextField
            error={amountstate}
            type="number"
            value={sairam}
            onChange={onchange}
            label='Please enter the amount'
            helperText={amounthelper}
            variant="outlined"
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => addBalance()}>Add Balance</Button>
    </form>
    </>);
    const [country, setCountry] = useState(false);
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('');

 const addBalance = () => {
        console.log("Clicked :)")
        console.log(sairam) // outputs the inital value not the changed value

});
    return(<>
    <div className="balance-container">
        <div className="columns-top">
            <div className="column-top">
            <h1>${upcoming}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="column-top">
            <h1>${balance}</h1>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleOpen}>Add Balance</Button>
            </div> 
            <div className="column-top">
            <h1>${lastmonth}</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <h2 id="transition-modal-title">{header}</h2>
            
            {modalchild}
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
     </>
    )
}
```

if I change the state sairam by using the function setSairam() the state is not getting updated and its only logging the initial state which is 0 i have even tried the loggint the event value of my input it works correct but the state alone is not changing please help me feel free to give me any other options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setSairam()` is the asynchronous method so you can't get the updated value of `sairam` immediately after `setSairam()`.

```
const onchange = async (e) => {
    setSairam({amount: e.target.value})
    console.log(sairam) // This will console old value of sairam
}
```

You should use `useEffect` with adding a `sairam` dependency to check the updated state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(sairam) 
}, [sairam]);
```

---

### IMPORTANT

`sairam` will be the value of the TextField, so you should update the sairam to the string value, not object.

```
setSairam(e.target.value)
```

Comment: well i am trying to get the value after some time but i am getting the initial value

Comment: in your above codebase, you are trying to get the value immediately inside onChange

Comment: i'm so sorry i forgot add another pice of code let me add it first

Comment: please check the function addBalance() where I am trying to fetch the value and getting the initial value

Comment: i think it should work, however can you check if you can see the updated value of sairam using useEffect that is written in my answer?

Comment: let me try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You will not get the updated value in your `onChange` function because that function is not aware when state is changed.

Use useCallback to get the updated value of `sairam`. Pass `sairam` in the dependency array.

```
const onchange = useCallback(async (e) => {
        console.log(sairam) 
        setSairam({amount: e.target.value})
    },[sairam]);
```

or use `prevState`

```
   setSairam(prevState => {
     console.log(sairam) 
    return ({amount: e.target.value})
  });
```

Another option is to pass `sairam` to onChange function. But I am not sure how it works since your markup is stored in state

```
onChange={(e)=>onchange(e, sairam)}


const onchange = async (e, sairam) => {
        console.log(sairam) 
        setSairam({amount: e.target.value})
    }
```

Comment: i will go with the third option but even though use the function setSairam later after a button click when i try to get the state it's showing me as 0

Comment: That can happen since you are not updating `modalchild`. Can you try the first method using `useCallback`. Or provide the markup you stored in `modalChild`  directly in your `return`. Is there any reason storing markup in state?

Comment: Yeah the reason for storing the markup in the state is that after I get the input from the user I will change the state to a different markup

Comment: Better not to keep markup in state, use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in return. Check this  [What Shouldn’t Go in State?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state)

Comment: Thanks for the idea!! mate I will implement it for sure